# Explorer sidebar style for .net

Tags: .net, user-controls

does exists some .Net component (free or paid) that emulate the XP Explorer side bar (like accordion, with grouping) ?
Thanks

Comment: What's the objective? having a file manager? or just to use the Tree View?

Comment: Something like a treeview ... a menu  categorized...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the few links which can help you.

1. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/OutlookBar.aspx
2. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ThemedExplorerControls.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My company is a subscriber for the Telerik Products, so I get this for free though I never use the component

> [RadFileExplorer for ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer.aspx)

[image]

[image]

They have a demo of the control, where you [can do some tests](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx).

I work with Telerik for some time (3 years now) and they are great, good Support response and all... though, I'm a premium user :)